# Is this "Individual Values" tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

I happened to notice that [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290782/in-pok%C3%A9mon-go-can-the-other-ivs-be-in-the-same-range-as-the-strongest-iv) had an unfamiliar [individual-values](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/individual-values) tag on it. Curious, I did a search to see if other questions related to IVs in the Pokemon series had this tag, but apparently it is a new tag.

I feel that it's worth mentioning that there *are* quite a few questions about Pokemon that relate to how IVs work, especially for Pokemon Go, so this tag would not go unused.

However, personally, I don't think this specific feature of the series really needs its own tag, but I wanted to get other opinions on this instead of just removing it. Should this tag stay?

Comment: Nope. I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

This tag should be removed.

Tags are an extra catalog system to more easily find questions concerning a certain game, and to have an easy way to identify all questions for a specific game. People use tags to determine if they would be capable of answering a certain question.

I am not aware of any other game-specific mechanic that we have given a tag. a tag for IV would be too specialized, and the tag subject is easy enough to search for manually in combination with a tag for whatever pokemon game you're playing.

We already have a wild growth of tags which have only 1 or maybe 2 questions attached, and many of those tags are simply duplicates of other tags that should not have been made in the first place. These legacy tags are now too old to remove, but we should do our best to not add any new ones.

Comment: Apologies if I'm incorrect, but I think a good example of game-specific mechanic tag would be any of the Diablo 3 class tags, like [the Crusader tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/diablo-3-crusader/info).

Comment: I agree that we don't need an 'individual values' tag, it's too specific a mechanic. It *could* potentially be covered by a '[competitive-pokemon]' tag which encompasses other aspects of competitive Pokemon other than just IVs, but I don't see it being needed yet. As for other game-specific mechanics that we have given a tag: [tag:minecraft-redstone], [tag:tf2-mann-vs-machine], and [tag:steam-trading-cards] as a starting point.

Comment: @Robotnik, that makes sense. I just wanted to make sure that my feelings were the same as other peoples' so I didn't remove a tag that other people saw value in. (I've been wrong about the legitimacy of a tag before)